# How to skip field validation when this field is disabled.Use react-hook-form v7 and Controller component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

## Problem:

i use react-hook-form and @mui/material
for this i need pass render prop like TextField cmp (from mui) to Controller cmp (react-hook-form)

i expect when TextField will become disabled validation skip for this field
but validations trigger in any cases and i get errors from disabled field

when use `register` without Controller  `<input {...register('someField', {disabled: true})/>` - its works, but i need same result with Controller component

## i try:

- just add prop disabled to field

```
<Controller
            name="secondField"
            control={control}
            shouldUnregister={true}
            //rules={{required:true}}
            render={({
              field: { onChange, value, ref },
              fieldState: { error },
              formState
            }) => {
              console.log(error);
              let commonFieldVal = watch("commonTextField");
              //let isDisabled = commonFieldVal === "bob";

              return (
                <TextField
                  label={"secondField"}
                  disabled={true}
                  error={!!error}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  ref={ref}
                />
```

- add prop shouldUnregister to field

**code:**

```
import {
  useForm,
  Controller,
  ControllerFieldState,
  ControllerRenderProps,
  FieldValues,
  UseFormStateReturn
} from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField, Button, Box } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

let CommonTextField = ({ error, value, onChange, setSecondFormState }) => {
  let isDisabled = value === "bob";
  useEffect(() => {
    setSecondFormState(isDisabled);
  }, [isDisabled]);
  return (
    <TextField
      label={"commonTextField"}
      error={!!error}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
/////////////////////////////////
const schema = yup.object({
  commonTextField: yup.string().required("commonTextField is required"),
  secondField: yup.string().required("secondField is required")
});
/////////////////////////////////
export default function App() {
  /////////////////////////////
  //  useForm
  let {
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    reset,
    formState,
    setValue,
    control,
    getValues,
    getFieldState,
    register,
    unregister
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { commonTextField: "", secondField: "" },
    shouldUnregister: true,
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  let { errors } = formState;
  let [secondFormIsDisabled, setSecondFormState] = useState(false);
  console.log(errors);
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log("Succes Submit FORM DATA----->> ", data);
        reset();
      })}
    >
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", gap: "10px" }}>
        <Controller
          name="commonTextField"
          control={control}
          render={({
            field: { onChange, value },
            fieldState: { error },
            formState
          }) => {
            console.log(error);

            return (
              <CommonTextField
                error={!!error}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                setSecondFormState={setSecondFormState}
              />
            );
          }}
        />

        {!secondFormIsDisabled && (
          <Controller
            name="secondField"
            control={control}
            shouldUnregister={true}
            //rules={{required:true}}
            render={({
              field: { onChange, value, ref },
              fieldState: { error },
              formState
            }) => {
              console.log(error);
              let commonFieldVal = watch("commonTextField");
              //let isDisabled = commonFieldVal === "bob";

              return (
                <TextField
                  label={"secondField"}
                  disabled={secondFormIsDisabled}
                  error={!!error}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  ref={ref}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Box>
      <Button type="submit">SUBMIT</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

---

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-glitter-lwqltp?file=/src/App.js)

**UPD:**
I use this hack temporarily:
remove YUP validation and transfer it to rules react-hook-form ...
when need to display disabled field use something like that:

```
    {!secondFormIsDisabled ? (
          <Controller
            name="secondField"
            control={control}
            shouldUnregister={true}
            rules={{required:true, ...secondFieldValidation}}
            render={({
              field: { onChange, value, ref },
              fieldState: { error },
              formState
            }) => {
              console.log(error);
              //let commonFieldVal = watch("commonTextField");
              //let isDisabled = commonFieldVal === "bob";

              return (
                <TextField
                  label={"secondField"}
                  
                  error={!!error}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  ref={ref}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        ): <TextField disabled={secondFormIsDisabled} />}
```